# Wrong character set is displayed in Chrome for mac and IE (for traditional chinese)

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, utf-8, character

On this page: http://eliv.com.tw/elivqa/ all the traditional Chinese characters are displayed incorrectly on Chrome for mac and IE (other browsers seem to work fine). In my Wp-config file utf-8 is specified. So I wonder why utf-8 is not chosen by some browsers. Any help is very welcome.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have resolved the issue by placing <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"> in the head

Answer (score 0):

Usually in your header.php of your theme you should have after your head tag something like this:

```
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
```

It is weird that this is missing from head tag in the first place.
Also you seem to have duplicate meta with name="viewport"